# return single instance of message django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i'm trying to create a p2p messaging system in my chat app (not using channels) so in my view.py i list out all messages, but i don't want it to list out multiple messages from a single user, just the most recent, sad to say it does the exact opposite, if brings out all messages between 2 people instead of only the most recent,

i tried creating a different models so i can filter by that and add the distinct function, but still didn't work, i really wanna get this done by christmas, so i appreciate any help

views.py

```
def pmpage(request):
     user = recceiver.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
     all_message = pm.objects.filter(recepient=user).distinct()
     unread = pm.objects.filter(recepient=user, unread=True).order_by('sender').distinct()
     sent =  pm.objects.filter(sender=request.user)
     context = {
          'all_message' : all_message,
          'unread' : unread,
          'sent' : sent,
     }
     return render(request, 'message.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class recceiver(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class pm(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recepient = models.ForeignKey(recceiver, related_name='recceiver', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    unread = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.body}'
```

thanks again

Comment: What means "only the most recent" ? The current week messages? The 5 last messages?

Comment: Most recent message sent to the request.user by each user